# When is "an" used instead of "a"?

Tags: grammar, vowels

Please resolve an "argument"

Which of the following is correct:

Post an HTML snippet

Post a HTML snippet

I believe it's the first - that the sound/vocalization, not the spelling, is what requires "an" instead of "a"; in other words "HTML" has an "A" sound and is, thus, verbally, a vowel. Am I wrong? The second possibility grates on my ears, and is as dissonant as all get out.